# how can I dynamically add key in array of object?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr=[];
$.each($("#id").serializeArray(), function (i, field) {

    arr.push({
        field.name : field.value
    });

 });
```

I want field.name should be dynamic.

Comment: _"I want field.name should be dynamic."_ ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: this is showing  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . (dot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
var arr=[];
$.each($("#id").serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
   var obj = {};
   obj[field.name] = field.value;
   arr.push(obj );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

It is because, LHS contains a `.` in

```
arr.push({
    field.name : field.value //field.name on LHS contains a dot, which is not correct syntax
});
```

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (section 6 Objects)

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens
>   surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. A name is a string. A
>   single colon token follows each name, separating the name from the
>   value. A single comma token separates a value from a following name.

If your property name is dynamic, then use bracket notation as @Satpal has shown above.

```
var obj = {};
obj[field.name] = field.value; 
arr.push(obj);
```